# How to make longer shadow

Tags: shadows

I have a shadow in this scene that only shadows his head and a part of his leggs, if you look closer you can see that the shadow goes away.
How can I make my character's shadow 100% on the ground?
[image: Jake with small shadow]
Thanks

Kind regards,
Gamer_io

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your lighting is all around your character causing little to no shadow. Position most of your Light sources on the left side to achieve a bigger shadow.

This is not related to the question, but please avoid thanking people on this site for the convenience of other readers(I know from experience and I apologize if that came off harsh).

Comment: Do you maybe know how I can fix that? I'm only using 1 light source, the sun.

Comment: Perhaps remove the sun and add and position a lamp manually.

Comment: No, still doesn't work. Maybe my computer is too weak.

Comment: Your computer shouldn't be a problem... You are following a tutorial yes? If so, copy exactly what they did, and if you already did then ask them this question.